# typescript error when using data structures in vue-chartjs

Tags: vue-chartjs

The vue-chartjs Line chart wants a type of

> ChartData<"line",(number | Point | null)[],unknown>

as data.

[In native chartjs you are supposed to adjust the type. (ChartData <'bar', {key: string, value: number} []>)](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#typescript)
How do I assign my data variable with the datastructure to the Line component without getting an typescript error?

I could give it the custom type and before giving the data variable to the component cast it as any to get no typescript errors? Is there any better solution? How do you do it? Or is that an issue for the github repo?

Comment: I am also getting a type error with Line Chart , but not with Pie Chart. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: no, I am still using the cast as any before assigning it...